# Dropshadow on Viewpager Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, clipping

I would like to put a shadow on the right side of a fragment inside a viewpager. An example would be the Shazam app, when you swipe the first view across, it has a shadow to the right.

I attempted to do this by creating a 10dp wide gradient the height of my main fragment (which is a relative layout, and setting it to align to the right of the parent, with a -10dp margin on the right. Unfortunately, nothing is drawn once it's moved outside of the fragments relative layout.

The xml for my main fragment is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/home_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeShadow"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/home_shadow"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have searched and can not find anything that says whether I can draw outside of the fragments relative layout or not. I found a clipChildren setting which I attempted on the relative layout and elsewhere to no effect.

Is there a way to have something drawn outside the boundaries of the fragments relativelayout?

If not, any suggestions on getting a shadow drawn to the right of a fragment as you swipe it across the screen?

Comment: Did you ever find out whether it's possible to draw outside?